In terms of Material Science, why do household garbage bag seal water and air, but allow odor to pass through?
In a household garbage bag (the common 13 gallon or 33 gallon ones in the US), some baby diapers were inside.  I already twirled the bag opening like 5, 6 times, and then use an extremely tight knot to seal it with some string.
So water or even air would not leak outside of the bag, but I noticed that it start to stink, and the odor seems to be just outside of the plastic layer all around the bag. So such plastic bag can seal water, and if I press on bag, it behaves like an inflated balloon which cannot allow the air inside to get out, but it would still allow odor to pass through? (in a way, the odor is smaller than the oxygen or nitrogen molecules?)

So porosity of a 0.5 mm layer of polyester vs liquid vs. gas.

Molecules of gas and water can slowly dissolve into and diffuse through many plastics. In fact, thin layers of polyethylene (which trash bags are made out of) readily pass water molecules, so much so that a trash bag is like a "screen door" for water vapor.
Note that water is odorless, so when the trash bag passes water you can't smell it.
The "stink molecules" are also soluble in polyethylene and many other plastics and will readily diffuse into it and pass through it- and then you can smell them.
Note that the stink molecules from rotting meat are quite soluble in the plastics used in car interior panels and trim, which means that a dead body that has rotted inside a car will render the car unsalvageable because it's impossible to extract all the decomposition products from the plastic once they soak into it. Those molecules also diffuse into the interior paint in the car which will then stink for years.
How do I know? The TV program "Mythbusters" did a segment on this in which they placed a dead 200# hog in a Chevy Corvette, closed it all up, and allowed it to ripen in the sun. The stink was so bad that mid-experiment they had to roll the Vette into a shipping container and bolt the door shut. They then endeavored to clean it up (nothing worked) and tried to sell it (no one bought it). they had to sell it to someone who wanted only the motor and transmission; everything else had to be thrown away.
Furthermore, I had a friend in college 50 years ago whose father was the county coroner for Shasta County in northern California. He had to respond to a report of a Porsche 911 which had been found abandoned in the middle of nowhere with the driver's body, well-ripened, behind the wheel.  The car itself was declared "unsalvageable".

I have a possible explanation in mind, let me first give some background.
An oil-like substance will readily dissolve into another oil, but not into water. Water and oil-like substances repel each other. (The reason why that is occurs is known, but in this answer I'll skip that story.)

Supposition: the material of the garbage bag is oil-like. Then it forms a barrier to water. If water cannot dissolve in the garbage bag material then it cannot pass that barrier.
Substances with a strong smell are quite often substances that dissolve well in oil. So if the garbage bag is made of a oil-like material then the odorous molecules can dissolve into the material and migrate to the other side.
(Fun fact: in chemistry there is a name for a particular category of molecules: 'aromatic'. Molecules of that type are poorly soluble in water.)

A plastic consists of long molecules. Depending on how much crosslinks there are the material is stiff or flexible.
A plastic bag needs to be flexible. The flexibility comes partly from the sheet plastic being ver thin, but still, to achieve flexibility the manufacturing process must keep the density of crosslinks low . I expect that having a low density of crosslinks makes it easier for molecules to dissolve into it.

Air consists for the most part (4/5th) of Nitrogen molecules (2 Nitrogen atoms forming a molecule) and for the rest mostly Oxygen molecules (2 Oxygen atoms forming a molecule).
The Nitrogen molecules and Oxygen molecules are significantly smaller than the odorous molecules.
The thing is: it takes time to migrate through the material. To the Nitrogen molecules and Oxygen molecules the soft plastic is like a thick molasses.
The large odorous molecules migrate are bigger, so they migrate even slower. The reason you are smelling it: just a tiny, tiny amount is already enough for you to smell it.



[LATER EDIT]
As pointed out in the answer by Niels Nielsen, there is no need to suppose that water does not dissolve in polyethylene. Water that migrates through the polyethylene will evaporate when it reaches the surface, and the outside will never even feel damp.

Your smell and taste buds are very sensitive detectors.
Tiny little presence of "stink" molecules in the air triggers the warning but the pressure drop in the bag is negligible.
